# How to generate methods to set and get properties at class instantiation with Python?

Tags: python, class, pytorch, instance-variables, python-class

I have a class containing tensors that have an unpredictable list of properties.

I would like it to generate a list of properties with getters and setter based on a list given at instantiation.

Do hou know how to do that ?

Thanks

```py
class Items:
     
    def __init___(
        self,
        names: List[str]
    ):
     #: Property names to be generated 
     self.names: List[str] = names
     #: Tensors in use
     self.tensors: Dict[str,Tensor] = {}
     
     def get_tensor(self, name:str) -> Tensor | None:
         if name in self.tensors.keys():
             return self.tensors[name]
         return None
         
     def set_tensor(self, name:str, tensor: Tensor):
         self.tensors[name] = tensor

     # The exact same setter and getter functions have to be generated for several properties:
     # entries, classes, scores, target classes, target scores, embeddings, heatmaps, losses...
     # The list is provided by self.names at instantiation 
     
     @property
     def entries(self) -> Tensor | None:
         return self.get_tensor("entries")
         
      @entries.setter
      def entries(self, tensor: Tensor):
           self.set_tensor("entries", tensor)
```

Comment: When an attribute is looked up on an object (assuming no overloading), Python checks if `getattr(type(object),attr)` is a property, and if so calls that property with the object as the sole argument (i.e, `self`), with some exceptions. You could use `type` to duplicate the class of your object, tweak the new class you've created to set the properties as needed, and then place that in `__class__`.

Comment: I've implemented the above comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Two methods came to mind. Both are messy and don't always work well with linters, mypy, etc. Basically, copy and paste or just using the get and set methods you have already are probably cleaner, clearer and easier solution. But if you're dealing with lots of properties or different classes then these should work.

Option 1: use **getattr** and **setattr** instead of properties

```
from typing import Dict, Any


class Tensor:  # just a test class for debugging
    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
    
    
class Items:
    def __init__(self, *names: str) -> None:
        self.names = set(names)
        self.tensors: Dict[str, Tensor] = {}

    def __getattr__(self, name: str) -> Any:
        if (names := self.__dict__.get('names')) and name in names:
            return self.tensors.get(name)
        try:
            return self.__dict__[name]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError(f"'{self.__class__.__name__}' object has no attribute '{name}'")

    def __setattr__(self, name: str, value: Tensor) -> None:
        if (names := self.__dict__.get('names')) and name in names:
            self.tensors[name] = value
        super().__setattr__(name, value)


items = Items('entries', 'classes', 'scores', 'target_classes',
              'target_scores', 'embeddings', 'heatmaps', 'losses')
items.entries = Tensor('X')
print(items.tensors)
print(items.entries)
print(items.classes)
```

Option 2: use a metaclass to create all the properties you want when the class is created. You could then create a different class (or inherit a new class) for each set of property names.

```
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import List, Dict, Any, Tuple, Callable, Optional, Type


class Tensor:  # just a test class for debugging
    def __init__(self, name: str) -> None:
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return self.name


class ItemsMetaClass(type):
    def __new__(mcs: type, name: str, bases: Tuple[type, ...], 
                attributes: Dict[str, Any], tensor_names: List[str]) -> Type[ItemsMetaClass]:
        for tensor_name in tensor_names:
            attributes[tensor_name] = property(
                create_tensor_fget(tensor_name),
                create_tensor_fset(tensor_name))
        return super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, attributes)


def create_tensor_fget(tensor_name: str) -> Callable[[Items], Optional[Tensor]]:
    def fget(self: Items) -> Optional[Tensor]:
        if tensor_name in self.tensors:
            return self.tensors[tensor_name]
        return None
    return fget


def create_tensor_fset(tensor_name: str) -> Callable[[Items, Tensor], None]:
    def fset(self: Items, tensor: Tensor) -> None:
        self.tensors[tensor_name] = tensor
    return fset


class Items(metaclass=ItemsMetaClass, tensor_names=[
            'entries', 'classes', 'scores', 'target_classes',
            'target_scores', 'embeddings', 'heatmaps', 'losses']):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.tensors: Dict[str, Tensor] = {}


items = Items()
items.entries = Tensor('X')
print(items.tensors)
print(items.entries)
print(items.classes)
```

So I'm not sure I'd actually recommend either of those, but they're options.

Comment: The first option here seems to be the obvious way to go in this case. All the other approaches are fun, and cool - but this case screams for `__setattr__`  and `__getattr__` overriding.

Answer (score 2):

There's a much briefer way to do this than in the answer detailed above.

```
class Items:
    def __init__(self, names):
        self.names = names
        self.tensors = {}

        old_type = type(self)
        new_type = type(old_type.__name__, old_type.__bases__, dict(old_type.__dict__))

        for name in names:
            getter = lambda self, name=name: self.get_tensor(name)
            setter = lambda self, tensor, name=name: self.set_tensor(name, tensor)
            setattr(new_type, name, property(getter,setter))

        self.__class__ = new_type

    def get_tensor(self, name):
        return self.tensors.get(name)

    def set_tensor(self, name, tensor):
        self.tensors[name] = tensor
```

There are only a few things to note about this code.

Firstly, if `Items` was refactored in future to take keyword arguments via a metaclass, you will need to change line 7 to use `copy.deepcopy` to create `new_type` from `old_type` instead.

The other catch is the `name=name` part. If `name` wasn't bound to the `<lambda>` scope in this way, it would reference the final element of `names` due to being bound to the scope of `Items.__init__`.

Finally, you had some redundant code in `get_tensor` which was just a reimplementation of [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get). I replaced this with the latter.

## How does it work?

When Python looks up an attribute during the process of getting or setting attributes, it checks if the `type(object)`'s corresponding attribute implements the descriptor protocol. [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) implements the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), and so when Python looks up properties, we can use getters and setters.

So how does [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) work? In the single-argument `type(object)` case, all it does is check the [`__class__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#instance.__class__) attribute of that object. `__class__` itself is just a reference to the class of the object. So if we change that `__class__` attribute to a class of our own making, we can create properties that are only specific to an instance.

Finally, the three-argument version of `type` can be used to make new classes, being passed names, bases and other arguments. If you change this code in future to use a metaclass, replace this line with [`new_type = copy.deepcopy(old_type)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy).

From there, the code becomes relatively straightforward. We create an new class for our instance using `type`, iterate through the names and create properties, and then finally assign our new class to the `__class__` attribute.

Comment: Maybe use inheritance when creating `new_type` would be better than create it as a `sibling` class?  The obvious advantage (besides avoiding corner cases in cloning a class) is that `isintance(obj, Items)` would work for your instances

Comment: Nonetheless, this can be achieved without any dynamic class creation voodoo, simply implementing `__getattr__` and `__setattribute__` .

Comment: @jsbueno I actually considered such an approach at first, but it has the drawback that you end up running into other corner cases which are both harder to resolve and debug. The first of which comes to mind is `__init_subclass__`, which I'm sure there are workarounds for, but I'm equally sure other edge cases exist. It might be possible to achieve this via modifying `__bases__` to interfere with method lookup, which would also solve the `isinstance` issue, but this might very well make more problems down the line (one can foresee differences in object layout).

Comment: as for the "isinstance" issue, if inheritance is not used, the Python mechanism for that is called "virtual subclassing" - the easiest way to implement it is to have the base class inherit from `abc.ABC` (abstract base classes), and use that class's `register` method as a decorator to classes that do not inherit from it, but for which you want `isinstance` and `issubclass` to work as if they did.

Comment: I hadn't actually heard of that, that's much better! Thank you so much, I learnt something today!